# Two convex cones

Tags: reference-request, convex-analysis

Consider a convex cone $C$ (in some real vector space), with $C_1$ a convex subcone. I'm led to study elements $v\in C_1$ with the following "relative form" of extremality: if $v=x+y$, with $x,y\in C$, then $x$ and $y$ are both in $C_1$. Does this situation has a name in convexity theory?

Comment: Every convex cone contains zero by definition. So the union of two can never be disjoint. You mean that the intersection is only a face of both, and therefore a facet. Since you want to study those $v$, the only possibility for this is that $v \not\in C_2$, because since those a real cones, every point exept zero is a sum of two.

Comment: Therefore you really might to specify your situation more.

Comment: I don't know about its name, but you can show that generators of $C_1$ must all lie on the boundary of $C$ (not in interior of $C$). And I think this is an exact characterization (any subcone with all generators on the boundary has this property).